# GKE: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin using helm cluster unreachable

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

How can I use `helm` with the authentication plugin for GKE `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`.

Getting the credentials works fine:
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME`

Using `kubectl` to communicate with the cluster works fine, but if I want to use helm I get an error:

```
helm list -n default
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: authProvider cannot be provided in combination with an exec plugin for gke_CLUSTER_NAME_europe-west3-a
```

gcloud-auth-plugin Version:

```
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version
Kubernetes v1.26.2-alpha+038d2342e9672c4772e9ee48a3f1dd9438156eba
```

Any ideas?

I can use helm with several other (not GKE) clusters without a problem.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Seeing the same. Weirdly it works with kubectl but not helm. On version 3.12.0 of helm

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Helm Version, this is the table of compatibility:

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/version_skew/

From GKE v1.22 there is some deprecated auth plugins:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/auth-plugin

I suggest upgrading your Helm version.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your users section in your KUBECONFIG file , and there it should look like

```
- name: $NAME
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

To make kubectl use gke-gcloud-auth-plugin